# make one function for get Element By Id

Tags: php, forms, list, function

I am not sure how to go about resolve this problem I have one master list and then 64 category list which I am trying to make one function as the function is exactly the same. It works for first category but remaining categories the function is not working. This is my function:-

```
<script>
    function displayResult() {
    var options = document.getElementById('master').options;

    var values = [];
    var i = 0, len = options.length;

    while (i < len)
    {
      values.push(options[i++].value);
    }

    txt=(values.join(','));
        document.getElementById('masterlist').value = txt;
        }
    </script>
```

This is the part within my form that triggers function - `onclick="displayResult()"`

```
<form action="update.php" name="form1" method="post" >
<select name=category[] id=category multiple="multiple" >
<?php   
    $file = fopen("category.csv", "r");
    while (($row = fgetcsv($file, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $category = $row[0];
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $category;?>"><?php echo $category;?></option>
<?php
    }
?>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="masterlist" id="masterlist" value="">
<input type="submit" onclick="displayResult()" value="Save File" name="submit" >
</form>


<form action="update.php" name="form2" method="post" >
    <select name=category1[] id=category1 multiple="multiple" >
    <?php   
        $file = fopen("category1.csv", "r");
        while (($row = fgetcsv($file, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $category1 = $row[0];
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $category1;?>"><?php echo $category1;?></option>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="masterlist" id="masterlist" value="">
    <input type="submit" onclick="displayResult()" value="Save File" name="submit" >
    </form>


<form action="update.php" name="form3" method="post" >
    <select name=category2[] id=category2 multiple="multiple" >
    <?php   
        $file = fopen("category2.csv", "r");
        while (($row = fgetcsv($file, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $category2 = $row[0];
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $category2;?>"><?php echo $category2;?></option>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="masterlist" id="masterlist" value="">
    <input type="submit" onclick="displayResult()" value="Save File" name="submit" >
    </form>
```

Comment: Yes, because you have multiple inputs with the same id "masterlist". Rename those just like you did with "category1", "category2" etc.

Comment: Ok, but how do you target them in one function as I have 64 different categories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple approach would be as follows:

1. Make the ids for the masterlist unique. The id is the unique identifier for an element, and the browser knows that there can be only one element with a certain id in the webpage. So change them to `id="masterlist1"`, `id="masterlist2"` etc.
2. Then you can use the ids in the calls to displayResult:

   ```
   onclick="displayResult('masterlist1')"
   ```

   (with the correct ID in each button) and change the displayResult function to

   ```
   function displayResult(listID) {
   (...)
   document.getElementById(listID).value = txt;
   ```

However, my own preferred way would be to dispense with all those ids and use the fact that we already have unique forms. Each of the submit buttons is in its own form, so you can write

```
onclick="displayResult(this.form)"
```

in the inputs and

```
function displayResult(form) {
(...)
form.querySelector('input[name=masterlist]').value = txt;
```

in the script. Then you can throw away all occurrences of `id="masterlist"`.

Comment: Thanx, work 100% went your way with unique forms. Just shows again don't overthink logic there is simpler ways of achieving goal